# NonType object has no attribute user_email

Tags: django

models.py

```
class userDetails(models.Model):
         user_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         user_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
         user_email=models.EmailField()

class LoginDetails(models.Model):
      user_id=models.ForeignKey(userDetails,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      admin_id=models.ForeignKey(AdminDetails,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      driver_id=models.ForeignKey(DriverDetails,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      login_id=models.CharField(max_length=20)
      login_password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
      login_status=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here in LoginDetails model I will be inserting user_id if user is registering, driver_id when driver registering.

And I need To select users which have `status="not approved"` using `select_related()`.
But I am getting NoneType error when writing below code,

```
    user_list=LoginDetails.objects.all().select_related('user_id')
    for user in user_list:
        print(user.user_id.user_email)
```

Comment: Most obvious thing (without seeing error trace) - `user.user_id` is `None`. This possible because constraint on this field saying that it can be `null`. Can you check if user_id if it's not `None`?

Comment: bro, my first row in login_details have user_id null because it is a driver data and second row ccontains user data

Comment: Ok, but you used query on all `LoginDetails` objects, so both rows will be passed in the loop. You'll need or add `if user.user_id:` before print, or exclude `LoginDetails` with nullable `user_id` - `LoginDetails.objects.exclude(user_id__isnull=True)`

Comment: thanks for ur help. But my LoginDetails contains both user data and driver data. I want to take only user_data

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it seems like you're not following correct syntax.
Try:

```
user_list = LoginDetails.objects.select_related('user_id')
```